# Update creates new entry instead of updating it

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have a rather simple entity model where a user has basic information. If a user also has a provider function a OneToOne relation will be created to the provider table.

My issue is that if I update a user without any provider function it works as expected. The fields which changed get updated but no new entry gets created. If the user has a provider function, all fields of the user get updated and no new entry gets created. In the table of the provider information each updated creates a new entry and the new ID gets set in the user table.

```
@Entity()
export class Users {

    @Column('text', {primary: true})
    uid: string;

    @Column('text', {nullable: true})
    firstName: string;

    @Column('text', {nullable: true})
    lastName: string;

    @Column('text')
    email: string;

    @Column('text')
    password: string;

    @Column('text', {nullable: true})
    role: string;

    @OneToOne(type => Providers, providerData => providerData.user, {cascade: true})
    @JoinColumn()
    providerData: Providers;

    @OneToOne(type => Clients, clientData => clientData.user, {cascade: true})
    @JoinColumn()
    clientData: Clients;

    @Column('bytea', {nullable: true})
    photo: Uint8Array;
}
```

Update function:

```
async update(uid: string, dto: UpdateUserDto): Promise<Users> {
        const userToUpdate = await this.usersRepository.findOne(uid);

        try {
            const user = new Users();
            const provider = new Providers();
            const client = new Clients();

            user.email = dto.email;
            user.firstName = dto.firstName;
            user.lastName = dto.lastName;
            user.photo = dto.photo;
            user.role = dto.role;

            Logger.log(dto.email);

            provider.licensed = dto.licensed;
            provider.notes = dto.notes;
            provider.paymentOptions = dto.paymentOptions;
            provider.speciality = dto.speciality;

            user.providerData = provider;
            user.clientData = client;

            const updatedUser: Users = Object.assign(user, dto);
            updatedUser.uid = uid;

            Logger.log('Updated User with UID: ' + userToUpdate.uid);
            return await this.usersRepository.save(updatedUser);
        } catch (error) {
            Logger.log('Error updating user: ' + error);
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong or what is a better solution?

Comment: You are getting the existing user `userToUpdate` but then you do not edit the existing entity but instead you create a new one and save it. Instead update `userToUpdate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new user instead of updating the existing one. try to add this line

```
const editedUser = this.usersRepository.merge(userToUpdate ,updatedUser);
```

and then save it

```
return this.usersRepository.save(editedUser);
```